# Restlet client interface class

Tags: restlet

Restlet looks cool, but Im sorry,  I'm just banging my head all day due to lack of documentation on a simple client.

I've managed to crib some useful stuff from

http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/core/resource/client

But there is just nothing that actually works as a full download (which would be nice). For example is the Customer here a pojo only ? or must it implement Serializable (I think it must).

My specific issue is as follows:

I have some code which makes a call to a URL and gets back this:

```
{"result":"success","data":{"last_local":{"value":"889.66000","value_int":"88966000","display":"$889.66","display_short":"$889.66","currency":"USD"},"last":{"value":"889.66000","value_int":"88966000","display":"$889.66","display_short":"$889.66","currency":"USD"},"last_orig":{"value":"889.66000","value_int":"88966000","display":"$889.66","display_short":"$889.66","currency":"USD"},"last_all":{"value":"889.66000","value_int":"88966000","display":"$889.66","display_short":"$889.66","currency":"USD"},"buy":{"value":"889.00000","value_int":"88900000","display":"$889.00","display_short":"$889.00","currency":"USD"},"sell":{"value":"889.66000","value_int":"88966000","display":"$889.66","display_short":"$889.66","currency":"USD"},"now":"1388846889233438"}}
```

The bit I'm struggling with, is the MAGIC that happens as follows:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(….); // fine
IDataStruct resource = cr.wrap(IDataStruct.class); // <---- Magic here, but fine at Runtime.

        if(cr.getResponse().getStatus().isSuccess())  // fine
        {
        PriceObject price = resource.retrieve();//<--- get to this line but then everything blows up because no converter is found. I can't use Jackson because GAE does not like it
   }
```

The question is, what should the **IDataStruct** interface look like ??

Will.

Comment: Restlet in action is a great book which almost makes up for the broken RESTlet website.  Also, check out their github repository - the documentation is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Customer in the example is indeed a POJO. Depending on the converter you would use, you can make it serializable or not. BTW, Jackson should work on GAE, which issue did you encounter exactly?

IDataStruct should be a Java interface annotated with Restlet API annotations such as @Get, @Post, etc.

Regarding the user guide, you can find the edited version in GitHub, where I just fixed some of the broken links (will be published soon on Restlet.org):
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-sites/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/learn/guide/2.1/introduction/first-steps/first-client.md